# Unable to execute a cucumber jvm test in Eclipse

Tags: java, gradle, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I'm learning how to use cucumber-jvm to do BDD in my new java project. I'm using eclipse and my project structure is as follow:

```
LearningCucumber
 - src
   - test
     - java
       - RunTests.java
   - resources
     - Sample.feature
```

I'm also using gradle and have included the cucumber-core, cucumber-junit, cucumber-java and junit dependencies.

My Runtests.java looks like:

```
package test.java;

import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class RunTests {

}
```

On executing the RunTests.java class, I get the initializationError:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gherkin/util/FixJava
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.<clinit>(RuntimeOptions.java:29)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptionsFactory.create(RuntimeOptionsFactory.java:25)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.<init>(Cucumber.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gherkin.util.FixJava
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the Gherkin dependency which can be got from Maven Central.  I think they are up to 2.12 as of latest information.

You will also need to add the cucumber-jvm-deps in order for the test context to work

Comment: Still not able to execute the test, after adding in the above dependencies. When I execute the test through gradle, it complains of unable to find the .feature file

Comment: I'm also facing this issue.. Do you have any solution for this.? How did you fix it. Please advice

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the project structure to

> src/main/resources